# Pick and throw prefab model

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

I am using this code for cube picking and throwing, but when I use this code for picking prefab model(in my case fire extinguisher), it is not working.. please help me.. code is attached for cube.
actually I want to pick fire extinguisher and want to use to tackle fire, but I  am unable to pick fire extinguisher. I am using asset of fire extinguisher.

```
void start() {
    mainCamera = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");
}
void Update()
{
    if (carrying)
    {
        carry(carryObject);
        checkDrop();
    }
    else
    {
        pickup();
    }
}
void carry(GameObject o)
{
    o.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(o.transform.position,Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * distance,Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}
void pickup()
{
//  PickupCube.Addcomponent(Rigidbody);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        int x = Screen.width / 2;
        int y = Screen.height / 2;
        Ray ray =Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y));
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            PickupCube p = hit.collider.GetComponent<PickupCube>();
            if (p != null)
            {
                carrying = true;
                carryObject = p.gameObject;
                p.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
// Update is called once per frame

void checkDrop(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.F)) 
        dropObject();
}
void dropObject(){
    carrying = false;
    carryObject.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
    carryObject = null;
}
```

}

Comment: You say it's not working. That's pretty vague. How is it failing? Do you get any error messages? Can you describe what happens when the code runs?

Comment: I suspect your fire extinguisher prefab doesn't have a `PickupCube` script component attached to it, causiing `if(p != null)` to be false.

Comment: Thanks for reply... actually this script works fine for picking cube, but when attaching this script to prefab of fire extinguisher, then nothing happen, even no error.

Comment: I have attached this script to prefab, with their names change...@Draco18s